# Trouble Implementing Selection Sort in Arm Assembly

Tags: sorting, assembly, arm, selection-sort

So I'm having trouble with my program. It's supposed to read in a text file
that has a number on each line. It then stores that in an array, sorts it using selection sort, and then outputs it to a new file. The reading of and writing to the file work perfectly fine but my code for the sort isn't working properly. When I run the program, it only seems to store some of the numbers
in the array and then a bunch of zeroes.

So if my input is 112323, 32, 12, 19, 2, 1, 23. The output is 0,0,0,0, 2,1,23. I'm pretty sure the problem's with how I'm storing and loading from the array
onto the registers because assuming that part works, I can't find any reason why the selection sort algorithm shouldn't work.

Ok thanks to your help, I figured out that I needed to change the load and store instruction so that it matches the specifier used (ldr -> ldrb and str -> strb). But I need to make a sorting algorithm that works for 32 bit numbers so which combination of specifiers and load/store instructions would allow me to do that? Or would I have to load/store 8 bits a time? And if so, how would I do that?

```
.data

.balign 4
        readfile: .asciz "myfile.txt"


.balign 4
        readmode: .asciz "r"


.balign 4
        writefile: .asciz "output.txt"


.balign 4
        writemode: .asciz "w"

.balign 4
        return: .word 0


.balign 4
        scanformat: .asciz "%d"


.balign 4
        printformat: .asciz "%d\n"


.balign 4
        a: .space 32


.text
.global main
.global fopen
.global fprintf
.global fclose
.global fscanf
.global printf

main:
        ldr r1, =return
        str lr, [r1]
        ldr r0, =readfile
        ldr r1, =readmode
        bl fopen
        mov r4, r0
        mov r5, #0
        ldr r6, =a
loop:
        cmp r5, #7
        beq sort
        mov r0, r4
        ldr r1, =scanformat
        mov r2, r6
        bl fscanf
        add r5, r5, #1
        add r6, r6, #1
        b loop



sort:
    mov r5,#0  /*array parser for first loop*/
    mov r6, #0  /* #stores index of minimum*/
    mov r7, #0 /* #temp*/
    mov r8, #0 /*# array parser for second loop*/
    mov r9, #7 /*# stores length of array*/
    ldr r10, =a /*# the array*/
    mov r11, #0 /*#used to obtain offset for min*/
    mov r12, #0 /*# used to obtain offset for second parser access*/


loop3:
    cmp r5, r9 /*# check if first parser reached end of array*/
    beq write /* #if it did array is sorted write it to file*/
    mov r6, r5 /*#set the min index to the current position*/
    mov r8, r6 /*#set the second parser to where first parser is at*/
    b loop4 /*#start looking for min in this subarray*/

loop4:
    cmp r8, r9 /* #if reached end of list min is found*/
    beq increment /* #get out of this loop and increment 1st parser**/
    lsl  r7, r6, #3 /*multiplies min index by 8 */
    ADD r7, r10, r7 /* adds offset to r10 address storing it in r7 */
    ldr r11,  [r7] /* loads value of min in r11 */
    lsl r7, r8, #3 /* multiplies second parse index by 8 */
    ADD r7, r10, r7 /* adds offset to r10 address storing in r7 */
    ldr r12, [r7]  /*  loads value of second parse into r12 */
    cmp r11, r12 /* #compare current min to the current position of 2nd parser !!!!!*/
    movgt r6, r8 /*# set new min to current position of second parser */
    add r8, r8, #1 /*increment second parser*/

    b loop4 /*repeat */
    
    
increment:
    lsl r11, r5, #3 /* multiplies first parse index by 8 */
    ADD r11, r10, r11 /* adds offset to r10 address stored in r11*/
    ldr r8, [r11] /* loads value in memory address in r11 to r8*/
    lsl r12, r6, #3 /*multiplies min index by 8   */
    ADD r12, r10, r12 /*ads offset to r10 address stored in r12 */
    ldr r7, [r12] /* loads value in memory address in r12 to r7 */

    str r8, [r12] /* # stores value of first parser where min was !!!!!*/
    str r7, [r11] /*# store value of min where first parser was !!!!!*/
    add r5, r5, #1 /*#increment the first parser*/

    ldr r0,=printformat
    mov r1, r7
    bl printf
    b loop3 /*#go to loop1*/


write:
        mov r0, r4
        bl fclose
        ldr r0, =writefile
        ldr r1, =writemode
        bl fopen
        mov r4, r0
        mov r5, #0
        ldr r6, =a


loop2:
        cmp r5, #7
        beq end
        mov r0, r4
        ldr r1, =printformat
        ldrb r2, [r6]
        bl fprintf
        add r5, r5, #1
        add r6, r6, #1
        b loop2


end:
        mov r0, r4
        bl fclose
        ldr r0, =a
        ldr r0, [r0]
        ldr lr, =return
        ldr lr, [lr]
        bx lr
```

Comment: Have you tried single-stepping through your code in a debugger?  Also, ARM has addressing modes like `[r10, r6, lsl #3]` that would be useful for indexing an array of 64-bit elements.  A word is only 4 bytes, `lsl #2`.  (https://godbolt.org/z/xEraef8jY is an example of a C compiler using it, to verify the syntax).  But anyway, that should be easier than manually doing address math with `lsl` and `add` instructions.

Comment: It's weird that you're calling `printf` inside your loop, normally you'd just use a debugger, but I think that's fine.  Your code doesn't appear to depend on any of r0..r3 or r12 surviving across the call, and according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention#ARM_(A32) all of r4..r11 are call-preserved.

Comment: Thanks! I figured out the problem. I needed to use ldrb and strb to read in the integers properly. But I have to read in 32 bit integers so I was wondering what I would have to do to do that. Would I just have to change the specifier and the load and store instructions?

Answer (score 1):

> I figured out that I needed to change the load and store instruction
> so that it matches the specifier used (ldr -> ldrb and str -> strb).
> But I need to make a sorting algorithm that works for 32 bit numbers
> so which combination of specifiers and load/store instructions would
> allow me to do that?

If you want to read 32b (4 bytes) values from memory, you have to have 4 bytes values in memory to begin with. Well that should not be surprising :)

Eg if your input is numbers `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, each number is 32b value than in memory that would be

```
0x00000000: 01 00 00 00 | 02 00 00 00  <- 32b values of 1 & 2
0x00000008: 03 00 00 00 | 04 00 00 00  <- 32b values of 3 & 4
```

In such case `ldr` would read 32b each time and you would get 1, 2, 3, 4 with each read in register.

Now, you have in memory byte values (based on your statement that `ldrb` gives right result), eg

```
0x00000000: 01 
0x00000001: 02 
0x00000002: 03 
0x00000003: 04 

or same in one line
0x00000000: 01 02 03 04
```

So reading 8bit by `ldrb` gives you numbers 1, 2, 3, 4

But `ldr` would do read 32b value from memory (all 4 bytes at once) and you would get 32b value `0x04030201` in register.

Note: examples for little-endian systems

Comment: So if I wanted my code to have the capacity to read 32 bit integers, would I need to require that all integers be 32 bits long?

Comment: Of course, if you are reading 32b value, that value MUST be a 32b value in memory. You could scale values up and down and have them in different formats before saving/loading, but you should always read in same format as value was written.